# Laprint causing end of file during psfrag call

Tags: errors, psfrag, matlab

I am attempting to create and use file in my TeX document using `laprint.m`.  The `laprint` function call produces the `.tex` and `.eps` files as expected.  When I try to use `\input{filename}` though I get an error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@@@psfrag \input{SparsAvgPerf}
followed by:
\begin{psfrags} on input line 14 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

Both errors point to `\end{document}` in the uppermost file.  The errors do not change whether the `\input` call is inside or outside of my figure environment.  This is my first experience with `laprint` and `psfrag`, so I am not even sure where to begin debugging.

Edit:

```
    \documentclass{thesis}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color}
    \begin{document}
    \input{SparsAvgPerf}
    \end{document}
```

A TeX file of only that produces the same errors, where SparsAvgPerf.TeX is in the same directory, and is the unmodified file created by laprint.m

Comment: Can you give a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? You can't upload the EPS file, but you can show us the least amount of code producing the error.

Comment: As a side note, I'd rather use [`matlab2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz) I think.

Comment: A similar example, albeit with the `article` class and not some thesis class, worked fine for me, so I'm guessing that it's either something with the file generated by `laprint`, or some issue with the class (know idea what that could be though).

Comment: I tried as well with the standard article class and it caused the same problems.  The matlab2tikz works beautifully though, so it looks as though I will be using that as an alternative.  Thank you.

Comment: I added that as an answer then. If you still want an answer to the `laprint` issue, you should probably post either the `SparsAvgPerf` file, the `.m` file that created the file, or even both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of getting nice plots from MATLAB to a LaTeX document is to use [`matlab2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz), which creates a TikZ/PGFplots figure that can be input to your document.

This has the added benefit of working with `pdflatex` as well.

### A simple example

While the use is fairly straightforward, I thought I might add an example.

Below is a very simple MATLAB script, the TikZ/PGFplots file generated by this, and a minimal LaTeX document, where it is used. `matlab2tikz` must of course be in MATLABs path. Add the folder to the path by selecting File --> Set path in MATLAB.

Specifying the width and height of the plot in the MATLAB script isn't necessary. Neither is using custom macros, *e.g.*, `\plotw` and `\ploth` to define the width and height. The manual of `matlab2tikz` mentions this, so that it's a notch easier to change the parameters from within the LaTeX document. And if you have several figures that should be the same size, it is definitely convenient.

**The .m-file**

```
x = -10:1:10;
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('x^2')
title('Lovely plot')
matlab2tikz('demo.tex','width','\plotw','height','\ploth')
```

**demo.tex**

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.1.4.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2011, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scale only axis,
width=\plotw,
height=\ploth,
xmin=-10, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$x^2$},
title={Lovely plot},
axis on top]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid
]
coordinates{
 (-10,100)(-9,81)(-8,64)(-7,49)(-6,36)(-5,25)(-4,16)(-3,9)(-2,4)(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)(2,4)(3,9)(4,16)(5,25)(6,36)(7,49)(8,64)(9,81)(10,100) 
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**LaTeX document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for a little dummy text
\newcommand\plotw{8cm}
\newcommand\ploth{4cm}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \input{demo}
  \caption{Plotting}
\end{figure}
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]